# Onchange selectbox in Drupal

Tags: html, drupal-7, onchange

Hi Ladies and Gentlemen,
Where I work is currently transitioning to a site using Drupal 7. We are trying to get a temporary site up and running until our new site is finished. I am a complete newbie to Drupal, but managing ok. Anyway I have a page that has an onchange select box which is supposed to open a PDF file. I am unclear how to make the onchange function work. I have looked on several pages but everything is a little confusing. Here is the code I need to change :

```
<form name="cataloglinks" action="">

<p class="style2">

<span class="style3">
Other editions of the online DACC catalog are also available:
```

```
<select name="cataloglinks-list" size="1" id="cataloglinks-list    onchange="goPage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">"
<option value="." selected="selected">Select an edition</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog08-09.pdf">Catalog for 2008-2009</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog09-10.pdf">Catalog for 2009-2010</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog10-11.pdf">Catalog for 2010-2011</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog11-12.pdf">Catalog for 2011-2012</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog12-13.pdf">Catalog for 2012-2013</option>
<option value="catalog/catalog13-14.pdf">Catalog for 2013-2014</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with Drupal, it might be a HTML tags issue or missing `goPage()` javascript function.

Try to implement the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function goPage(path) {
      if(path != '') {
          window.location = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, '/'].join('') + path;
      }
  }
</script>

<select name="cataloglinks-list" size="1" id="cataloglinks-list" onchange="goPage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select an edition</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog08-09.pdf">Catalog for 2008-2009</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog09-10.pdf">Catalog for 2009-2010</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog10-11.pdf">Catalog for 2010-2011</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog11-12.pdf">Catalog for 2011-2012</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog12-13.pdf">Catalog for 2012-2013</option>
    <option value="catalog/catalog13-14.pdf">Catalog for 2013-2014</option>
</select>
```

**Note:** I assumed that catalog folder is in the root directory of your site.

Comment: Yes the catalog folder is there. Thank you for your reply. I will try this today.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately the onchange is still not working.

Comment: @Inky1231 can you check if there's any javascript errors?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Also I have tried to put the files in different locations thinking I had mapped the path wrong (right now our transition site is on at least 2 different servers... long story)

Comment: @Inky1231 install firebug on firefox and open the page that contain the dropdown and press f12 and go to console tab of firebug window/panel and you should see if there's a javascript error. Also have you tried to access pdf files without dropdown like, test it directly in the url  "www.domain.com/catalog/catalog08-09.pdf". Suggestion make sure to point the site to one server using the host file and try to see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you! We finally got some server issues worked out and I tried your solution above and it worked like a charm!!!